# create loop in R precipitation data defined interval start and end

Tags: r, loops, time-series, intervals, percentage

I want to analyse precipitation data from South America. My objective is to determinate onset and offset of the rainy season by using cumulative percentage rainfall of each year.

My data has the format

```
Date        Precip   
1939-11-01  0  
1939-11-02  0  
1939-11-03  0  
1939-11-04  4.9  
1939-11-05  0  
1939-11-06  0.7  
1939-11-07  3.5
```

`lapply1<-read.table("lapply.txt",header=T)`

`lapply1$Date<-as.Date(lapply1$Date)`

For a single year I do this by:

`cumsum(Precip/(sum(Precip)/100)`

I want to write a lopp starting at every year `y-07-01` and ending at `(y+1)-06-30`

I tried this:

```
lapply(lapply, function(cumsum(lapply1$Precip/(sum(lapply1$Precip)/100)), 
    ts(lapply1, freq=4, start=c(y-01-01), end=c(y+1-06-30), names(lapply1)))
```

I dont know how to set the start and end of the interval and to define.
Additionaly I have many NAs. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Did you mean to write `lapply(lapply, ...` in the last bit of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The R time series method `ts`, which you're trying to use, may be appropriate when there are an equal number of values per unit of time as in the case of months and years  where there are 12 months in every year.  However, since the number of days in a year changes due to leap year, for your daily data you might use the `zoo` package, which can represent irregular time series.   Using `zoo`, the only issue is that you start your year in the middle rather than at the end.  The following is one of way of working with that. This  code also deals with NA's in the data by removing them.

```
library(zoo)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, 
text="Date        Precip   
1939-11-01  0  
1939-11-02  0  
1939-11-03  0  
1939-11-04  4.9  
1939-11-05  0  
1939-11-06  0.7  
1939-11-07  3.5")
precip_data <- zoo(df[,-1, drop=FALSE], order.by=as.Date(df[,1]))

#  create data for example problem
#  remove following statements to process input data
  set.seed(123)
  precip_data <- zoo(5*rexp(365*76, 100), seq(start(precip_data), by="day", length.out=365*76))
  precip_data[as.integer(365*76*runif(10000))] <- NA
#
#  calculate start and end dates of years used to accumulate data
#
  yr_start <- as.numeric( format( start(precip_data),"%Y"))
  if( start(precip_data) < as.Date(paste(yr_start,"-07-01",sep=""))) yr_start <- yr_start-1
  yr_start <- as.Date(paste(yr_start, "-07-01",sep=""))
  yr_end <- as.numeric( format( end(precip_data),"%Y"))
  if( end(precip_data) > as.Date(paste(yr_end,"-07-01",sep=""))) yr_end <- yr_end + 1
  yr_end <- as.Date(paste(yr_end, "-07-01",sep=""))
  yr_seq <- seq(yr_start, yr_end, by="year")
#
#  replace NA's with zeroes
  precip_data_zeroes <- precip_data
  precip_data_zeroes[is.na(precip_data)] <- 0
#  accumulate precipitation for each year and then divide by end of year value to compute percentages  
  cum_precip_list <- tapply(precip_data_zeroes, cut(index(precip_data_zeroes), yr_seq), cumsum)
#  list of precipitation percents by year
  cum_precip_pct <- sapply(cum_precip_list, function(x) 100*x/as.numeric(tail(x,1)))
#  zoo daily time series of precipation percents for all years
  cum_precip_zoo <- do.call(rbind, cum_precip_pct)
#  add a column with cummulative percents to original data 
  precip_data <- merge(precipitation=precip_data, cum_pct=cum_precip_zoo)
#  save precipitation data and cummulative percents as a csv file
  write.zoo(precip_data, file="precip_data.csv", index.name="Date", sep=",")

#  set the number of plots per page
  plots_per_pg <- 3
  par(mfcol=c(plots_per_pg,1))
#  set the number of years per plot
  yrs_per_plot <- 10 
  num_yr <- length(cum_precip_pct)
  num_plts <- ceiling(num_yr/yrs_per_plot)
  for(i_plt in 1:num_plts) {
    i_yr <- (i_plt-1)*yrs_per_plot+1
    i_yr_end <- min((i_yr+yrs_per_plot-1), num_yr)
    plot(cum_precip_pct[[i_yr]], xlim= c(yr_seq[i_yr], yr_seq[i_yr_end+1]),
         xlab="Year", ylab="Cummulative Precipitation (%)", cex.lab=1.4, cex.axis=1.3, xaxt="n")
    axis(side=1, at=yr_seq[i_yr:(i_yr_end+1)], labels=yr_seq[i_yr:(i_yr_end+1)], cex.axis=1.3)
    lapply((i_yr+1):i_yr_end, function(x) lines(cum_precip_pct[[x]]))
   }
```

`cum_precip_pct` contains the cumulative percents as an R list of `zoo` time series for each year.  The first column of `precip_data` contains the original precipitation data and, in the second column, the cumulative percents for the entire period.

**UPDATE**

The code above has been modified to replace NA's with zeroes, to add the cummulative percent data as a column to the original precipitation data, and to save this as a csv file to disk.

I'm not clear on your intention for the plotting.  Putting seventy something years of daily data in one plot where every year is very similar to every other year doesn't show much detail.  As a more flexible alternative,  the code can now display multiple years of data on a plot with several plots per page.   The number of plots per page is set at 3 and the number of years per plot is set at 10 but you can change these as need be.  An example of these plots is shown below.

[image]

Comment: thank you for the fast replay it work´s perfectly! For comparison of diferent years it´s better to kepp na´s. Did you know how I can  plot all elements in cum_precip_pct in one plot together. I tryed it with plot() and lines(), doesnt work. How can I save cum_precip_pct? Thanks

Comment: The UPDATE above shows a way to save and plot the results

Comment: a very usefule answer! I decided to make a animated gif plot with the "animation" package

Comment: a very usefule answer! I decided to make a animated gif plot with the "animation" package plotting each year. In the last plot I want to plot all curves together with a mean curve. Untill now I cant figure out how to make this. I ploted lines at 10% & 90%(as on and offset of the rainy season. Did you have an hint how to get the dates (I tryed it with "which",works not in the loop), the amount of rain (from precip_data) and number of days without precipitation? Thanks!